# How to separate time ranges/intervals into bins if intervals occur over multiple bins

Tags: python

I have a dataset which consists of pairs of start-end times (say seconds) of something happening across a recorded period of time. For example:

```
#each tuple includes (start, stop) of the event happening
data = [(0, 1), (5,8), (14,21), (29,30)]
```

I want to quantify what percentage of the time this thing is happening within bins of any size that I desire. For example if I wanted bins of 5 seconds each I would like a function that would:

- split up any tuples that cross over into multiple bins
- add up the total time event occurs and divide by bin size to get time event occurred during each bin

I'm mostly having trouble with the first point.

Ideally it would look something like this where bin_times is the function that I need help writing, and the output is what the function would return:

```
data = [(0, 1), (5,8), (15,21), (29,30)]
bin_times(data, bin_size=5, total_length=40)

>> [20, 60, 0, 100, 20, 20, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Shouldn't (15-21) be (15,21), ie, with a comma?

Comment: sorry yes just fixed it

Comment: no worries, helps to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `numpy`, here is a strategy:

```
import numpy as np

def bin_times(data, bin_size, total_length):
    times = np.zeros(total_length, dtype=np.bool)
    for start, stop in data:
        times[start:stop] = True
    binned = 100 * np.average(times.reshape(-1, bin_size), axis=1)
    return binned.tolist()

data = [(0, 1), (5,8), (15,21), (29,30)]
bin_times(data, 5, 40)
// => [20.0, 60.0, 0.0, 100.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

To explain the logic of `bin_times()`, let me use a smaller example:

```
data = [(0, 1), (3, 8)]
bin_times(data, 3, 9)
// => [33.3, 100.0, 66.6]
```

1. The `times` array encodes whether your event is happening in each unit time interval. You start by setting every entry to `False`:

   ```
   [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
   ```
2. Read the incoming `data` and turn the appropriate entries to `True`:

   ```
   [True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
   ```
3. Reshape it into a two-dimensional matrix in which the length of the rows is `bin_size`:

   ```
   [[True, False, False],
    [True,  True,  True],
    [True,  True, False]]
   ```
4. Take the average in each row:

   ```
   [0.333, 1.000, 0.666]
   ```
5. Multiply by 100 to turn those numbers into percentages:

   ```
   [33.3, 100.0, 66.6]
   ```
6. To hide the use of `numpy` from the consumer of the function, use the `.tolist()` method to turn the resulting `numpy` array into a plain Python list.

One caveat: `bin_size` needs to evenly divide `total_length` — the reshaping will throw a `ValueError` otherwise.